# C++ container set + array functionality

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, c++14

Which is the best container in C++ which can -

- store only **unique** values (such as `set`)
- can lookup those values using **index** in constant time (such as `array`)

I basically need to to iterate in phase one and collect all the `unique` elements, order really doesn't matter.

However, in phase two, I then have to provide each element in the container, but can only provide it one by one. Since caller can know the size of my container, it provides me `index` one by one, such that 0 < idx < size of the container.

Right now, the only solution that comes to my mind is two maintain two containers `vector` and `set`, I am wondering is there any container that provides the same?

```
class MyContainer{
  private:
   std::set<Fruits> setFruits;
   std::vector<Fruits> arrFruits; // can have indexed access

  public:
    void collectFruits(const Fruits& fruit){
       if(setFruits.find(fruit) == setFruits.end()){ 
       // insert only if it doens't contains
          setFruits.insert(fruit);
          arrFruits.push_back(fruit);
       }
     }
 };
```

Comment: `set` also orders the values. Do you need them to be ordered, or merely that there be no duplicates?

Comment: no duplicates! order is not important!

Comment: unordered set has "Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity" which means O(1) on average.

Comment: You could use a vector, but with an custom insert function that checks for duplicates on insert

Comment: If order is not important, does that mean the order can change if something is added or removed?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about why you want to look up the values with an index? Since you don't require them to have stable order I'm struggling to see what benefit there is to look them up by index.

Comment: Are you trying to select N random numbers without duplicate or something?

Comment: Thanks, Matt but because of some interface, I can only pull the value on by one, and I can only provide indexes.

Comment: How about vector + bloom filter to detect duplicate at inserts?

Comment: I am not sure how does that work. Can you please point this to me?

Answer (score 4):

Alex Stepanov, the creator of STL, once said "Use vectors whenever you can. If you cannot use vectors, redesign your solution so that you can use vectors." With that good advice in mind:

Phase 1: Collect the unique elements

```
std::vector<Foo> elements;

// add N elements
elements.push_back(foo1);
...
elements.push_back(fooN);

// done collecting: remove dupes
std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
elements.erase(std::unique(elements.begin(), elements.end()),
               elements.end());
```

Phase 2: Well, now we have a `vector` of our `k` unique elements, with constant-time index access (with indices 0..k-1).

Comment: This can be expensive if there are lots of duplicates, though.

Comment: Thanks, Barry! But in that case I can even use `set` during collection and convert to `vector` to have constant-time index access..

Comment: @T.C. Absolutely. I'm just going on the [likely completely unfounded] assumption that phase 2 is the important one :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a boost [`flat_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html).

I don't think it provides an `operator[]` but it has random access iterators and has a constant time [`nth()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html#idp44105072-bb) function that returns an iterator with a particular index.

Inserting may invalidate iterators but providing you do all insertions in phase 1 and then all index access in phase 2 you should be ok.